# Absurdism is not the complete answer

Tags: existentialism, meaning-of-life, art, camus, absurdism

After experiencing existentialism for a number of weeks,I embraced absurdism.

However, after a month of experiencing absurdism as my end all and be all meaning of life philosophy, I come to believe that it is not in fact that. I have come to believe that absurdism is a huge stepping stone on the path towards the meaning of life. However, it is not the final.

I believe that the arts offer enlightenment towards the next step. However, I do not know how to act upon it. Although philosophers such as Camus have spoken on this topic before, I do not find their thinkings complete nor compelling enough to comprise them as the next step after absurdism.

If anyone would have any advice as to what they believe the next step after absurdism is, or how to act apon a lifestyle centralized around the arts would look like, that would be great.

Thanks!

Comment: i would suggest critical theory, especially if you find absurdism appealing but are unsure why

Comment: To help complete your own path of Absurdism's incompleteness, perhaps you're missing Kantian *ought implies can* deontic morality since Absurdism mainly establishes the reverse...

Comment: Nietzsche makes great points about art & it's power to lift us out of nihilism. You might like this answer about aesthetics & philosophy: 'Is beauty a basic human need?' https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/89414/is-beauty-a-basic-human-need/89456#89456

Comment: We stick to focused, factual Q&A on this site, so opinionated guidance is generally discouraged. As an absurdist, you essentially have three routes if you reject that the universe or gods provide you a meta-narrative to live a life. You build one for yourself (existentialism), you don't build one and celebrate not needing one (absurdism), and you reject meaning all together of any sort (nihilism). Camus did not consider himself an existentialism despite his existential preoccupation. If you reject absurdism, then its either existentialism (generally Sartre) or...

Comment: nihilism (generally Nietzsche and the radical post-modernists).