# Practical examples of moralities

Tags: ethics

When people talk about moralities, the only thing that comes to mind is Moses' Laws, i.e., the Ten Comendments. However, what are some other practical, perhaps even conflicting, examples of moralities?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could look at Confucian thought, where filial piety is held to be the highest moral value. I argue here that related to high costs of succession disputes: [Are there opposites to the "social contract theory" where humans are regarded as naturally social beings, and yet individualism is a human invention?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/78508/are-there-opposites-to-the-social-contract-theory-where-humans-are-regarded-as/78553#78553)

I would distinguish the morality of Abrahamic traditions, where submission to the deity is the highest moral value, from the Hellenic-influenced tradition where reason gives us access to knowledge of the order of the world including in morality. Christianity fused both traditions, though they have always been in tension there.

Hindu and Buddhist thought that accept rebirth, have a more psychological than materialist perspective on the world, leading to different moral reasoning.

In philosophy there are three main categories of moral reasoning. Going from something like revealed word scripture, is Deontological. Then there's virtue ethics, like Aristotle. And Consequentialist thinking, like Utilitarianism. You should read a general introduction like [The Definition of Morality](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/morality-definition/) (SEP).